# Can I compile my own WPF dll's>

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, com

I found WPF source code in this link:
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/src/

Can I use that source code to compile my own PresentationCore.dll?

I'm trying to do this because this dll is calling a system COM Object, penIMC.dll, that has an error.

My idea is to modify the code to call another dll, that solves the problem for my specific case.

Comment: @NETscape, I'm serious :) this is actually driving me crazy, and the source code is published but I don't know if that is the last version or what. It is not a duplicate, actually, the other question (also mine and no response) is about redirecting .NET to use my own dll instead of the one in ../Framework64/WPF folder. Both are related but not duplicate.

Comment: @NETscape, I don't think it's unreasonable. If the source code is available, why not? Maybe the fact that I come from the Linux world  I think in that way. Regarding the issue I'm 100% sure the issue is in a dll. PInvoke is not related to this. If I'm in the context of logonui, and I call function GetTabletCount in the COM object PenimcManager (penIMC.dll), it gets blocked and returns after a timeout at 30 seconds.

Comment: Hey man @NETscape, let me try what you suggest. Do you know how I can disable all tablet devices? It happens in all machines with special input devices (pen, digitizer, touchscreen) and also with .NET 4.5.2, be it 32 or 64 bits.No breakpoint set. It must return immediately and the return value depends on the input devices and it must be greater than 0.

Comment: @rodolk just because **reference code** is available, doesn't mean you can compile it. If there was a serious problem with touch devices in general, it would have been patched with an update but you can always open *Connect* ticket. In any case, you can't and shouldn't recompile PresentationCore.dll